# Queryset filter/excludes for dates

Tags: sql, django, datetime, filter, django-queryset

I have an event + dates type table design.

```
Class Event
   ...

Class EventDate
   ...
   date = models.DateField()
   event = model.ForeignKey(Event)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = ('date', 'event')
```

I'm trying to find events that are no longer happening, i.e. expired from today onwards.

I tried the following queryset:

```
 Event.objects.filter(dates_set__date__lt = 
 datetime.date.today()).exclude(dates_set__date__gte = datetime.date.today())
```

The SQL query seems odd to me because of the subquery, and it looks expensive.

```
SELECT … FROM "events" INNER JOIN "event_dates" ON ("events"."id" = 
"event_dates"."events_id") WHERE ("event_dates"."date" < '2013-05-02' AND NOT 
(("events"."id" IN (SELECT U1."event_id" FROM "event_dates" U1 WHERE (U1."date"
>= '2013-05-02'  AND U1."event_id" IS NOT NULL)) AND "events"."id" IS NOT NULL)))
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you need the exclude? Shouldn't either one work on their own, either filtering by dates less than today or excluding dates greater than or equal today?

Comment: Yup, looks like you are correct.

Is exclude the only way to do not equal? Say, I have an additional conditional that I want "status != expired" , how will I do that without running an exclude(subquery)

Comment: You can with [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects): `~Q(status="expired")`

Comment: Thanks. Can you post an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, the filter and the exclude are the same, so using one or the other should return the results you want.

Another way to do "exclusion" is to use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to make "not" statements. So if you wanted to get all events with `status != "expired"` and `date < today` you can use

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(dates_set__date__lt=datetime.date.today()), ~Q(status="expired"))
```

Comment: Thanks again. Must be one of my mental blocks days.